# How can I load C application with Assembly?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, nasm

It's the same idea as Operating system boot loader. I have a C source code and Assembly source code. I want the assembly code to pass control to the C application. I am working on Linux and using GCC + NASM for compiling. Do I need to compile them in a special way? What's the assembly code used to load the c application and start it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let gcc and nasm produce object files which you can link together. You have to use the right symbol names, too. In the NASM [manual](http://www.osdev.org/howtos/1/), you can find a nice explanation including examples. As it is not explained how to compile the examples using gcc and a linker, you can find these things explained [here](http://www.osdev.org/howtos/1/).